# calling AddAutoMapper once per assembly instead of passing in multiple assemblies?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a multi layered project with a web API project and a library project. Both projects rely on AutoMapper (and AutoMapper extensions for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection). Based on this

https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

in the Startup file I'm setting up AutoMapper for all the layers

```
Assembly apiAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Assembly myLibraryAssembly = Assembly.Load("MyLibrary");

services.AddAutoMapper(apiAssembly, myLibraryAssembly);
```

As you can see here, the API project needs to know about all the referenced library projects by loading them via name. I would prefer a way that every project is able to register itself. Based on this sample code

https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/master/src/Application/DependencyInjection.cs

I created such a file in my library project

```
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyLibrary(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); // MyLibrary assembly

        services.AddAutoMapper(executingAssembly);
        // ... setup other services

        return services;
    }
}
```

and in the API project I can now do this

```
Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

services.AddAutoMapper(executingAssembly);
services.AddMyLibrary();
```

The code seems to work fine but `AddAutoMapper` will be called twice. Once for the API assembly and once for the library assembly. Should I stick to the first approach because AutoMapper should only be added once or is it fine to separate it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The code seems to work fine but `AddAutoMapper` will be called twice. Once for the API assembly and once for the library assembly. Should I stick to the first approach because AutoMapper should only be added once or is it fine to separate it?

You should stick to the first approach, because `AddAutoMappper` does nothing when called for the second, third etc. time, thus profiles and other AM related types from the assemblies passed to these calls won't be registered.

It can be seen in the beginning of the [implementation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L62) of the private method which is called by all public `AddAutoMapper` overloads:

> ```
> private static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapperClasses(IServiceCollection services, Action<IServiceProvider, IMapperConfigurationExpression> configAction, 
>     IEnumerable<Assembly> assembliesToScan, ServiceLifetime serviceLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Transient)
> {
>     // Just return if we've already added AutoMapper to avoid double-registration
>     if (services.Any(sd => sd.ServiceType == typeof(IMapper)))
>         return services;
> ```

followed by the actual registration code, which at the end registers `IMapper`.

Currently there is an open issue [Allow usage of Options Pattern to configure AutoMapper #132](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/132) with exactly the same concerns as yours.

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer was correct at the time but it would appear that things have changed in the recent past.

The AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection package has been [updated](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/releases/tag/v8.0.0) to allow the call to AddAutoMapper() multiple times.

See PR [Use Microsoft.Extensions.Options to configure AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/pull/135) for details.  You will need to update the package to [version 8.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/8.0.0) or higher to use it.

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use abp moudule system to make the library register for themselves.

The doc is here: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Module-Development-Basics

But the framework is a little heavy.If you don't want to use it,

I think you can do it this way: every library register the automapper itself ,and call the other library's register function it depends on.

Each library can add a helper class to do the registration

```cs
public static class ApiRegisterHelper
{
    public static Assembly GetAssembly()
    {
        return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    }
    public static IServiceCollection AddLibrary(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Assembly executingAssembly = GetAssembly(); 
        services.AddAutoMapper(executingAssembly);
        DaoRegisterHelper.AddLibrary(services);
        return services;
    }
}

public static class DaoRegisterHelper
{
    public static Assembly GetAssembly()
    {
        return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    }
    public static IServiceCollection AddLibrary(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Assembly executingAssembly = GetAssembly(); 
        services.AddAutoMapper(executingAssembly);
        OtherRegisterHelper.AddLibrary();
        return services;
    }
}
```

I havn't tested it,but it might be work.Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply. If I understood correctly you said that calling `services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` once per project is fine :)

Comment: @Question3r Yes. The main idea of dependency management in multi layered projects is : each moudle handle the dependency for itself, this is not just for automapper. You can have a look at abp module system:<https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Module-Development-Basics>